# Remove "?query=" from my URL

Tags: html

So I am making a VERY simple Chrome extension which allows someone to click it, then type in a French word, it will then take the word and redirect you to a french dictionary.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div id="pattern" class="pattern"> 
        <form action="http://www.wordreference.com/fren/" method="get" class="f" target="_blank"> 
                            <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search Videos.." /> 
                            <input type="submit" class="btn search-submit" value="Search"> 
                        </form>
```

However this does not work, when I enter in a word, instead of taking me to

```
www.wordreference.com/fren/Bonjour
```

It takes me to

```
http://www.wordreference.com/fren/?query=Bonjour
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Should be noted changing the text query to 'a' will take me to

```
http://www.wordreference.com/fren/?a=Bonjour
```

Comment: don't use a form - you'll have to use `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **POST** method in **form**.

```
<form id="my_form" class="f">....</form>
```

**target="_blank"** is for **a tag** (not in form):

```
<a href="url_here" target="_blank">Test url</a>
```

If you want to change the **output URL**.

Try to use redirect method (script) like:

```
window.location.href = custom_url+'?'+form.serialize();
```

Sample script for Form submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).readY(function(){
    $("form#my_form").on("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var parameters = $(this).serialize();
      window.location.href = "?a=" + parameters;
    });
 });
</script>
```

Modify the **url** as you wish.

Comment: Ok so using this gets me to 'wordreference.com/fren/' but doesn't enter in my word that I have to enter each time I use this extension

Comment: I should let you know that I am very bad at HTML, I have tried all of your answers many times but am having trouble implementing them